# Parse JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json

I am sending data from my iOS app to my server in json format. Here is the format.

```
{
  "email" : "email",
  "password" : "password"
}
```

How can I get these variables in PHP? I actually want to get the parameters like that

```
$json = $_POST['jsondata'];
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);

$email         = $data['email'];
$user_password = $data['password'];
```

If I can't get the data like this, please tell me how should I send the data so that the backend can accept my data?

Comment: This should be the correct way. What is your problem with this?

Comment: I faced same issue when get request from iOS app, and rectified in below manner. Refer my answer

Comment: problem is I can't receive the variables on server. If I do like this it says jsondata is undefined because there is no variable coming as jsondata in my json

Comment: Do you send your data with POST, GET or something else? Did you try to ``print_r($_POST);``?

Comment: Well, are you passing the json above in a form variable called jsondata? Where does this 'jsondata' name come from? If you're just passing the raw json then you need to get the post body, as in anto's answer

Comment: @anto.nishanth yes I am working in IOS SWIFT and I am sending POST data from IOS APP

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 I am sending POST data. no I didn't try it.. let me try

Comment: @JimL I want to pass the json in form variable. but at the moment I am sending raw json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below

Method 1:

```
$json = file_get_contents( 'php://input' ); // RECEIVE INPUT JSON STRING

        $data = json_decode($json, TRUE);

        $email         = $data['email'];
        $user_password = $data['password'];
```

Method 2:

```
fopen(DOCROOT."json.txt","w+");

file_put_contents("json.txt", $_POST);
$recoreds = file_get_contents('json.txt', true);

$json_a=json_decode($recoreds, true);
```

Comment: have you printed `$json` jest before `json_decode($json, TRUE);`

Comment: try printing `print_r($_REQUEST)` and see are you getting the values as you expected.

Comment: i think I am doing something wrong in my app. hang on

Comment: @hellosheikh you may try the second method also, but you should modify little bit if there are multiple request to php script is possible at a time. Also you should manage to delete the json.txt file after processing it

Comment: well your solution works. if you works on IOS too as you said, I need some help in that code too. actually I want to send this json in variable so I receive the data in variable rather then doing this file_get_contents( 'php://input' );

Comment: @hellosheikh I am not purely working on iOS other mate is working on iOS and I am processing with magento, so aware of this issue.

Comment: @hellosheikh gald it helped you.